# 3D mapping of Velodyne scans

Tags: 3d, mapping, registration, point-cloud-library, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to map the environment with pointclouds obtained from a Velodyne VLP-16 mounted on a moving car. I am trying to use ICP algorithm from the pcl, but the results are awful.

I think that too many points are different in one scan from the next one, but still look very similar, so instead of thinking the car is
moving ICP thinks is still.

I am not very sure what could I try to obtain a good registration of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Give an initial guess to ICP from odometry or IMU data.
2. Velodyne scan takes 100 milliseconds, so make sure the pose estimate is separate for each slice of this scan. If the car turns steeply, say 45 degrees in 1 second, the points within one scan can already be misaligned from each other by 0.100*45 = 5 degrees. That makes 87 centimeters in the range of 10 meters.